# Что означает строка (window).ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Что означает строка:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    generateWindowID();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объявляет функцию, которая будет вызвана после загрузки DOM. Читайте документацию.
[jQuery: .ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)